# Как конвертировать QTableView to QWebView

Tags: c++, qt

При запросе в Базу данных использую QSqlQueryModel, добавляю эту модель в QTableView все хорошо, отображается. Мне необходимо эту табличку перевести в PDF. Знаю как сделать из QWebView в PDF с помощью QPrinter и QWebView::print(). Но возникла сложность при конвертации из QTableView в QWebView. Конечно можно брать отдельные элементы ячеек и заполнять с помощью html тэгов, но есть ли более элегантный способ для подобной конвертации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любой QWidget, в том числе QTableView, можно отпечатать в виде pdf.

```
void printToPDF( QWidget* w ) {        
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setOutputFileName("output.pdf");
    // printer.setPageMargins(12, 16, 12, 20, QPrinter::Millimeter);
    // printer.setFullPage(false);
    // ...

    QPainter painter(&printer);
    // painter.translate( ..., ... );
    // painter.scale( ..., ... );

    w -> render(&painter);   
}
```

Но, с высокой вероятностью, клиента это не устроит, поскольку ему нужно не то что он видит на экране, а что-то другое... Проще обойти в цикле все строки / ячейки и сформировать HTML документ вручную, со стилями, колонтитулами и т.д., а потом его отпечатать в PDF.